# Best way to find matching element of array for given string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying find out the matching element of an array for a given string.

```
var array = ["CODE1", "CODE2", "CODE3", "CODE4", "CODE5", "CODE6"];


var text = "alsdjklfjaaCODE2ladkslfj";
var resultCode;
for (var i in array) {
    if (text.indexOf(array[i]) > -1) {
        resultCode = array[i];
    }
}
console.log(resultCode);
```

But I felt that it is not efficient way to iterate through array as that array was little big. Is there any alternative algorithm for my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by *best matching element*?

Comment: now I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

As of ES6, you can use [**Array.prototype.find**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [**Array.prototype.includes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
var array = ["CODE1", "CODE2", "CODE3", "CODE4", "CODE5", "CODE6"],
  text = "alsdjklfjaaCODE2ladkslfj";

var resultCode = array.find(a => text.includes(a));

document.write(resultCode);
```

Comment: Since it's ES6, `array.find(a => text.includes(a));`

Comment: @BenFortune, uhhh, nice one! :-) thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

if you expect only one match in the string. The iteration stops if the callback returns `true`.

```js
var array = ["CODE1", "CODE2", "CODE3", "CODE4", "CODE5", "CODE6"],
    text = "alsdjklfjaaCODE2ladkslfj",
    resultCode;

array.some(function (a) {
    if (~text.indexOf(a)) {
        resultCode = a;
        return true;
    }
});

document.write(resultCode);
```